# Read server-provided cookie from React frontend

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt

First off: I'm quite new to React, so please bear with me.

I have a React frontend app written by a co-worker which I now need to extend to do JWT authentication as part of deployment to a cloud platform. The platform on which the app will run prescribes that the app needs to read `sessionid` and `x-xsrf-token` from a cookie sent by the server. In case it matters, the React app is deployed to Cloud Foundry, and the authorization server is part of the same platform. React is version 16.4.2.

I have searched far and wide and have not come across a way to read the value of the document cookies from within the React app. What I found were examples of setting my own cookies, then later reading them back, such as with CookiesProvider in react-cookie. I also found that one could use express, but this didn't work for me as express seems to conflict with React.

Am I missing something really simple? How to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you see the cookie in dev-tools?
note that if a cookie has the [`HttpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies) flag then the client (`javascript`) cannot read it or even check if it exist.

Comment: Yes, I can see the cookie in dev-tools, and `HttpOnly` is `false`.